# Why isn't my UserControl keeping its initialization?

Tags: c#, user-controls, initialization

I have a UserControl for which I *think* I'm initializing some of the members:

```
// MyUserControl.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private string m_myString;
        private int m_myInt;

        public string MyString
        {
            get { return m_myString; }
            set { m_myString = value; }
        }
        public int MyInt
        {
            get { return m_myInt; }
            set { m_myInt = value; }
        }

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyString = "";   // was null, now I think it's ""
            MyInt = 5;       // was 0, now I think it's 5
        }

        // .........
    }
}
```

When I insert this control into my main form, though, and call a function that checks values within `MyUserControl`, things don't look like they're initialized:

```
// MainForm.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this prints 0 rather than 5
            MessageBox.Show(this.theUserControl.MyInt.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is a *really* simple error but I don't know where.  I've tried prepending `this.` to things, but this probably isn't the way to go about fixing code. :)

Thanks as always!

**EDIT:** Stepping into the designer code as Pete suggested showed me where the write-over was happening.  First I called the constructor of the user control, and then later, the values got overwritten with default values.  I hadn't specified any default values (Sanjeevakumar Hiremath's suggestion) so the default values were those of the primitive types (for `int` this was 0).

Comment: `private string m_myInt;`, the property is int.  Post code that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: What does your designer code look like?  Have you set a breakpoint on your UC constructor code to see what's getting hit and when?

Comment: @Hans: Sorry about that! I was changing variable names to generic things and forgot to change that.

Comment: It still isn't legal.  MyUserControl is a *type* name, the property isn't static.  When you drop the control on the form, the default name for the control instance variable is myUserControl1.

Comment: @Hans: Man, it's one of those days. You're right.  Fixed that typo too.

Comment: @Pete M: The overwrite was happening in `InitializeComponent()` for the main form.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're likely seeing here is an artifact of the designer.  If you ever opened up `MainForm` in a designer after you added `MyUserControl` it likely recorded the default values of `MyUserControl` in the generated `InitializeComponent` method of `MainForm`.  These recorded values are re-assigned after the constructor of `MyUserControl` runs hence they're overwriting the values you set.

You can control this behavior via the use of the `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx#Y375

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.Content has the effect of generating code only for what is seen in the designer, not what's part of the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Use [[DefaultValue]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  Attribute. It lets you specify default value for a property of a control when the value is not specified in the designer.