# What things trigger Visual Studio to regenerate a *.Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, designer, windows-forms-designer

Some form initialization issues [I was having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544818/why-isnt-my-usercontrol-keeping-its-initialization) were traced to the .Designer.cs file overwriting values I had initialized in a user control's constructor.

I had designed a component (`MyUserControl`) and inserted it into a form (`MainForm`).  I later added some member initializations in `MyUserControl`'s constructor, but the code that was in `MainForm.Designer.cs` for `InitializeComponent()` was stale, and code later in that functions was overwriting the my new initializations from the constructor called earlier in that function.

So, in essence, something I did triggered a rewrite of `Mainform.Designer.cs` but other activities didn't.

Is there a good reference that describes when the designer touches the *.Designer.cs files?  (Or is it a simple rule?) Jared Par pointed me to the [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) class but that seems to be one tree in the forest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specifically fell victim to having code for the old version of your UserControl still embedded in the form's InitializeComponent() method.  If you would have removed the control from the form before modifying the control code then you wouldn't have had the problem.  Removing it afterwards and putting it back would have fixed it too.

Yes, it is a simple rule.  InitializeComponent() is re-generated every time you add or remove a control to/from the form.

Comment: (++) Thanks Hans.  Is adding/removing the control more or less the *only* way to get InitializeComponent() to "refresh?"  If so, I can see a lot of fairly subtle bugs creeping in to a solution.  It would be nice to have something more automated than that.

Comment: This isn't any different from changing public members of a regular class.  You always run the risk of breaking some other code that uses it.  Or that existing code breaking the edited class.  The designer actually makes it a lot easier to fix that kind of breakage, you only have to remove the control and put it back :)